# Why variable gets reset on button click(s) in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-button

Can someone help me to understand what is happening here? Have been trying to debug, but feel like stuck!

I am trying to animate some online images in my Android app using the following method.

```
private void animateImages() {
 
        // URL loading
        // int i = 1; (initialized earlier)
        // ArrayList<String> myImages = new ArrayList<>(); (initialized earlier)
        myImages.clear();
        While (i < 11) {
        // Adds ten images using web link
        myImages.add("My_web_url");
        i++;
        }            

        AccelerateInterpolator adi = new AccelerateInterpolator();
        try {
            Field mScroller = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            mScroller.setAccessible(true);
            mScroller.set(viewPager, new MyScroller(getApplicationContext(), adi, 1));
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), myImages));
        }
 
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            // Printing variables for debugging 
            System.out.println("The page number is=" + currentPage);
            System.out.println("The myImages size is=" + myImages.size());
            
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == myImages.size() - 1) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
 
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
            // delay and period can be initialized as desired
        }, delay, period);
    }
 
}
```

When I call this method in `OnCreate`, animation works fine. However, when I call this method in `OnClickButton Listener`, variable `myImages` size (before `public void run()`) become zero and due to this animation doesn't work.

In the above, `MySCroller` and `MyPageAdapete`r are java classes. But, most likely, the issue is related to button click, and I don't understand why it resets the myImages size which halts the animation!

This is how button click listener is called. What am I doing wrong?

```
MyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        animateImages();
    }
});
```

**Edit 1:**

Thanks to all the comments, I made a little progress.

I moved all these variables from MainActivity to animateImages() method. The animation runs with button click as well but there is a bump in animation, where too images moves too fast then bump and so on..

```
// Added just before while loop
DELAY_MS = 1000;
PERIOD_MS = 1000;
i = 1;
currentPage = 0;
```

I notice the same animation bump if I move the URL loading while loop to `OnCreate()`.

Comment: `While (i < 11) {` <-- where is `i` declared? And where is it modified?

Comment: Put it inside runOnUiThread(){}

Comment: @Michael: After `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {....}` and Before `OnCreate` where all variables are initialized

Comment: Ok, well, it's unclear to me from the code you've posted how that `while`-loop is supposed to work since you haven't shown us where `i` is modified.

Comment: @ `i` is declared as `int i = 1;` after `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {....` and before `OnCreate`. It is mainly used to start the while loop from `1` that goes til `10` to load ten images into array string, so it is used in the beginning of private `animateImages()` method.

Comment: But where is it modified? To me your `while`-loop looks broken since it loops while `i < 11` but doesn't appear to increment `i`. Also, you unconditionally clear `myImages`, but only add images to it if `i < 11`. Is that the intended behavior? What is the relationship between `i` and the number of elements in `myImages`.

Comment: @Michael: yes, sorry, there is `i++` after url load link. Just modified the code.

Comment: The second time you call that it clears `myImages` but then doesn't loop because `i` is not reset. Move creation of that list to onCreate instead.

Comment: @Michael: `i` is mainly to load 10 images so initialized at `1`.  So, i = 1 will tell the While loop to get my_image1.png, i = 2, my_image2.png and so on. The URL doesn't change, but the images  get updated periodically, that's the reason, each time method is called, previously loaded images are cleared and reloaded. Makes sense or Is it the wrong approach?

Comment: What is the point of having a separate variable `i` instead of just using `myImages.length`? Like I mentioned, you unconditionally clear `myImages`, but only add new images if `i < 11`.

Comment: I made a little progress based on comments. I moved all the animation-related variables to `animateImages()` method and now animation runs on button click as well. But, the issue is, it runs "normally" in OnCreate, and on button click, it runs a bit faster. Like there is a bump in animation, where two images scrolls too fast, then bump, then next images too fast..

Comment: @Michael: The idea was to get the images in a loop instead of  hardcoding several links and add to the array list, there i was used and initialized at 1.

Comment: @TylerV: I moved URL loading and `i` to OnCreate. Animation runs on button click as well. I ran into another issue [ there is a bump in animation, it runs faster and faster on each click, although `delay` and `period` are fixed in the beginning with values 1000, 1000 but still, there is a strange bump :/ ]. I might post a new question, but your comment ATM answers the question, care to post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second time you call `animateImages` it clears `myImages` but then doesn't loop because `i` is not reset so it remains empty. Move creation of that list to `onCreate` instead to avoid that issue.